# how to insert an array field (brand new) while updating a document (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

I have a TEST collection like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "tags" : [
        "technology"
    ]
}
```

now I am trying to insert another array field during the update. e.g. query is:

```
db.TEST.update(
   { _id: 1.0 },
   { $set:
      {
        "musings.0.rating": 2
      }
   }
)
```

expecting the collection to be:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "tags" : [
        "technology"
    ],
    "musings" : [
         {
            "ratings": 2
         }
    ]
}
```

but it updates it like this where **musings** is added as a regular field and not as the array field:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "tags" : [
        "technology"
    ], 
    "musings" : {
        "0" : {
            "rating" : 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use special update operator for array.

```
db.TEST.update({
  id: "1.0",
  $push: {
    musings: {
      ratings: 2
    }
  }
})
```

`$push` operator append element to array. If array field doesn't exist it is created.

Here are details for array update operators: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/